# Nailgun: how to run jar files?

Tags: java, jvm, executable-jar, nailgun

I installed nailgun on my OSX and the server is started:

```
NGServer 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT started on all addresses, port 2113.
```

When trying to run a simple jar file (expecting some outputs), nothing happens, the command is executed but there is no output on the CLI:

```
ng /Users/miloscuculovic/PycharmProjects/XMLDiffAnalyzer/XMLDiffTools/jndiff/jndiff-ui.jar
```

When runing

```
java -jar /Users/miloscuculovic/PycharmProjects/XMLDiffAnalyzer/XMLDiffTools/jndiff/jndiff-ui.jar
```

All works as expected.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363931/how-run-a-simple-java-program-with-the-client-server-nailgun-on-debian-stretch) suggests running `ng ng-cp` first – perhaps that helps. I guess your input to `ng` is somehow not what it's looking for. It seems like bad design on part of `ng` to emit no output when given invalid input – for example, `ng lkjlkjlkj` returns, no errors/warnings.

Comment: Thanks @kaan, I was reading the post you mentioned and they only mention calling the xxx.class file, not mentioning the jar. Is ng compatible with jars? Is there a way telling nailgun to be verbose?

Comment: .jar files are supposed to work according to docs. You might find something to try by looking at [client source](https://github.com/facebook/nailgun/blob/master/nailgun-client/c/ng.c). Another idea: run the nailgun server inside a debugger, maybe you can tease out some clues when a client connection comes in.